# How can I forward-declare/prototype a function in Python?

Tags: python, function-prototypes

How do I prototype a method in a generic Python program similar to C++?

```
# Prototype
# Do Python prototyping

writeHello() # Gives an error as it was not defined yet

def writeHello():
    print "Hello"
```

Comment: Just define `writeHello()` **before** calling it. There is no such thing as 'prototyping' in Python. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: I like to define my function at the bottom of the program, a habit from Java and C++. I wanted to know if there was a way to prototype in Python.

Comment: @GeorgeClone-y This feature just does *not* make sense in Python. This is because Python method definitions *are just code* that is executed (and thus must be executed prior to being resolved/invoked); in Java and C++ the methods are compiled to a meta-structure.

Comment: @GeorgeClone-y: Then you have to put all remaining code into a `main`-function and call `main()` in the last line of your program.

Comment: Modern Python has [type annotations/hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) and [stub files (.pyi)](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs.html).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Python does not have prototyping because you *do not need it*.

Python looks up globals *at runtime*; this means that *when you use `writeHello`* the object is looked up there and then. The object does not need to exist at compile time, but *does* need to exist at runtime.

In C++ you need to prototype to allow two functions to depend on one another; the compiler then can work out that you are using the second, later-defined function. But because Python looks up the second function *at runtime instead*, no such forward definition is needed.

To illustrate with an example:

```
def foo(arg):
    if not arg:
        return bar()

def bar(arg=None):
    if arg is not None:
        return foo(arg)
```

Here, both `foo` and `bar` are looked up as globals when the functions are called, and you do not need a forward declaration of `bar()` for Python to compile `foo()` successfully.