# How to call function that will be defined later?

Tags: python

As title. I want to move code segment `if __name__ == '__main__':` before all functions that it will call.(I found this more readable, for myself) To achieve this I need to call functions that will be defined later. Is this possible?

While this has been answered in the comment section. To provide more context: I read one line of code:

```py
cur_mod = sys.modules[__name__]
```

which let me came to this question. (i.e. I thought it would be possible to call something defined later by import itself)

Comment: No. Put your: `if __name__ == '__main__':` below all the defined functions. Just call functions as necessary below this line.

Comment: Function definition and call are 2 separate things. You can define the function and then call it in the `if __name__` block.

Comment: You could have the other functions in another file and import it before this segment.

Comment: You can't call something that hasn't been defined yet, and Python doesn't "hoist" function definitions like some other languages do. So: no. You can put your code into a `def main` at the top which you call at the bottom…?

Comment: you could make this work.. in a weird way which involves bizarre stuff like reading the file, separating `if __name__ ==....` from the rest of it, then `exec` all of that, then `exec` that `if` block or sth, but no, don't actually do it

Comment: @deceze: Thank you. This is reasonable. I will adopt this way.

Comment: @VimNing You could put all of the code executed below the `if __name__ == __main__` call into yet another function, and put it at the very top of the file... Then just call that function and it will do the same thing

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341192/how-to-forward-declare-prototype-a-function-in-python

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to wrap the invocation into a function of its own.

So that

```
foo()

def foo():
    print "Hi!"

will break, but

def bar():
    foo()

def foo():
    print "Hi!"

bar()
```

will be working properly.

General rule in Python is not that function should be defined higher in the code but that it should be defined before its usage.